# Help understanding a proof of Łoś-Vaught test

Tags: logic, model-theory

I am trying to understand a specific proof of the following statement:

> Given $T$ a $\kappa$-categorical theory with no finite model, $T$ is complete.

Let $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal N$ be two models of $T$. We want to prove that $\mathcal M\equiv\mathcal N$.
Using Löwenheim-Skolem's lemma, one can find $\mathcal M'$ and $\mathcal N'$ models of $T$ of cardinal $\kappa$ that extends $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal N$.
Since $T$ is $\kappa$-categorical, $\mathcal M'\simeq\mathcal N'$.

So far I understand the proof. But then it goes:

$\mathcal M\equiv\mathcal M'$ and $\mathcal N\equiv\mathcal N'$ so since $\mathcal M'\equiv\mathcal N'$, we have $\mathcal M\equiv\mathcal N$.

I don't understand why we would have $\mathcal M\equiv\mathcal M'$ and $\mathcal N\equiv\mathcal N'$.

Comment: The Löwenheim-Skolem theorems (upward and downward) should have been used to get models of size $\kappa$  $\mathcal M'\equiv\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal N'\equiv\mathcal N$, not models of $T$ extending  $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal N$. (The latter wouldn't even make sense if $\mathcal M$ or $\mathcal N$ were bigger than $\kappa$.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass Doesn't the lemma gives $\mathcal M'$ such that $\mathcal M\preceq\mathcal M'$ (or using the the downward lemma $\mathcal M'\preceq\mathcal M$) rather than $\mathcal M\equiv\mathcal M'$? I get you can construct one model in both directions but why would they coincide?

Comment: Go up to a cardinal $\geq\kappa$, and then from there go down to $\kappa$. (That's why I wrote "upward and downward"; in general you need both.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you very much for the answer but I feel like I am missing something
I understand why we need both to have the exact kappa cardinal, but what I don't understand is why we have elementary equivalence

Comment: @AndreasBlass $\mathcal M'\preceq\mathcal M$ implies $\mathcal M'\equiv\mathcal M$, I was missing that, thank you

Comment: The upward step produces an elementary extension of $\mathcal M$ and the downward step produces an elementary submodel of that. Since elementary extensions and elementary submodels are elementarily equivalent (and since elementary equivalence is transitive), you end up with a $\kappa$-sized model elementarily equivalent to $\mathcal M$.